# Best way to handle WCF message authentication in the cloud (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, azure, cloud

I've looked to many sources, and found many examples, but none really fit the situation that I hope to take a project to. I am writing a bunch of WCF services, some publicly accessible, others not (server to server), that will allow a fully flexible cloud app that ensures the ability to scale out the service as needed through Azure. I am unsure which way to go with message authentication, as I want to make sure a particular user logged in, can perform different tasks, and prevent others from running those tasks.

Most of what I have seen uses roles or ASP.NET membership. I have my own custom membership users will use to login with, and I don't rely on standard membership providers, or active directory. What is your recommendation? I thought about just creating a token that is created on successful login, that is stored within a cookie, added as a parameter passed into each method, but with some research, I think this might be able to be handled without modifying all my methods.

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily implement authentication without needing to manually pass a token into all your functions by using UserNameAuthentication and writing a custom validator - there is a fairly straightforward tutorial [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2007/10/05/wcf-authentication-custom-username-and-password-validator.aspx)

If you use UserNameAuthentication, you will need to use SSL/HTTPS, which means you'll need to get a server certificate - this is a good idea anyway for most business applications.

At the server side you can get the identity of the current user:
`IIdentity wic = OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity as IIdentity;`

Comment: Awesome, that helped a lot! I'm going to create a test project to look at this more in depth. Quick question though, once a user is authenticated, how do I gain this information on future requests? Meaning, user 123 authenticates, how do I know it's user 123 on the next request? How do I maintain state? Is it a matter of storing something in a cookie? I'm sure there's multiple options, but for a cloud-based solution, I'm wondering what the best option is?

Answer (score 0):

use basic authentication and have the webservice authenticate against your membership store.